# Resize event with NWSE cursor indicates just Default cursor

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, cursor

I want to detect if a resize started from the grip / south-east corner of a form. When i check the cursor within the Resize event, even that i see a SizeNWSE-cursor, it detects a default cursor.

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Cursor == Cursors.SizeNWSE)
   {
         // doesn't reach this point although i see a NWSE cursor
   }
}
```

Why doesn't it detect a Cursors.SizeNWSE cursor? Is there another way to detect a resize started from the grip? The background is that i want to resize an image within the form as streched, but as proportionally whenever a resize starts from the corner. I had some image viewer that did just this but i've lost it and can't remember the name so i try to develop my own one.
Any hint highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong property, the Form.Cursor property doesn't change when you start resizing.  It is Windows that overrides the Cursor.Current property, the modal loop that resizes a window is implemented in Windows itself.  This works fine:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) {
    if (Cursor.Current == Cursors.SizeNWSE) {
        Console.WriteLine("lower right corner");
    }
    base.OnResize(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The form's `Cursor` property is not affected in the non-client area of the form.
I advise to determine whether both the `Height` and the `Width` properties of the form has been changed.
Try this code in the form's class:

```
private int oldWidth;
private int oldHeight;
private bool areBothChanged;

protected override void OnResizeBegin(EventArgs e)
{
    oldWidth = Width;
    oldHeight = Height;
    areBothChanged = false;
    base.OnResizeBegin(e);
}

protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    areBothChanged |= Width != oldWidth && Height != oldHeight;
    ...
    base.OnResize(e);
}
```

Comment: Good idea, i will try this as well.